Flickering effect on Angular Material Table
I have a problem with the MatTable component from Angular Materials.
I have some columns with conditional styling, so I use [ngStyle].
I need to refresh the data in this table quite regularly (every 5 seconds). Therefore, I use this.dataSource.data = newData.
When I do this, there is a flickering effect on the ngStyle CSS, which is quite visually unappealing.
How can I fix this problem?

I think a better solution would be to use a WebSocket which changes the table content only if It got updated.

The flickering effect may cause due to frequent re-rendering of table.

You can use trackBy function to avoid re-rendering of whole table.
Use ngClass instead of ngStyle if possible.
This is highly unlikely but if your table does not have fixed height with overflow auto or does not have paginator, frequent increase or decrease in row can make it look like flickering.

